# Pyramid: does a session have to be a dict

Tags: python, session, pyramid

I am trying to implement my own session factory in Pyramid. All the session factory examples I have seen (beaker, redis, etc.) implement it as a subclass of `dict`:

```
request.session['key'] = 'value'
```

I want to implement a very simple session interface:

```
request.session.set('key', 'value')
request.session.get
request.session.delete
```

Is this OK? Does this affect any internal methods of Pyramid to function incorrectly? Do any Pyramid sub-systems depend on sessions being dict-like?

EDIT:

The default [`SessionAuthenticationPolicy`](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/authentication.py) does depend on session dicts

```
def remember(self, ...):
    ...
    request.session[self.userid_key] = principal
```

Comment: Why? You are also making a key-value mapping. Might as well use a familiar interface/syntax.

Comment: I understand. But what if I want to do something esoteric on the session data that I'd like to encapsulate in a method: `session.xyz()`? Or, I want to prevent the `delete` on session keys. Or maybe, I simply don't want to provide the entire dict interface

Comment: Nothing stops you from defining extra methods or overriding `__delitem__`

Comment: Again you're right! But, I want a restrictive approach where I only want to expose few methods on session and treat it as a black box representing user session.

Comment: Then don't subclass dict, but still define `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` instead/along with your accessors.

Comment: Yep. You're right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things you have seen so far are conforming themselves to Pyramid's `ISession` interface. If you want arbitrary packages to be able to touch your session (such as the `SessionAuthenticationPolicy`), you must provide a session implementation that conforms to the interface these packages expect.

That's what Pyramid expects to operate effectively. That being said, very very few packages actually require a valid session, so you're typically fine doing whatever you want (until you can't :). If you want to provide other methods for your application to use, on top of the original interface, that's completely fine.

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/api/interfaces.html?highlight=isession#pyramid.interfaces.ISession

Comment: Alright. The more I understand the internals of Pyramid, the better I feel.